# Bad SQL Request - Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, one-to-many

i need help about sql request...

I have
**parameter** who have many ->
**subparameters** who have Many ->
**filteredSubparameter**

id do this request :

```
   $parameter->subParameters()->whereHas('filteredSubparameter', function ($query) {
        $query->where('filteredSubParameter.item_id ', '=', 2);
    })->get();
```

That do :

```
Unknown column 'filtered_sub_parameters.sub_parameter_id'
```

the request should be :

`filtered_sub_parameters.item_id` and not `'filtered_sub_parameters.sub_parameter_id'`

Thanks so much

Comment: `query->where('item_id ', '=', 2);` would this work, maybe?

Comment: nop, that's said same thing, thank you for trying